# CakePHP saveAll repeated and non-repeated entries

Tags: cakephp

Well,

I created a Model with the following restriction

```
public $validate = array(
        'player_id' => array(
            'rule' => array(
                'checkUnique',
                array(
                    'player_id',
                    'game_id'
                ),
                true
            ),
            'required'      => true,
            'allowEmpty'    => false,
            'on'            => 'create',
            'message'       => 'Same player_id y game_id'
        )
    );
```

So each time I try to create a game record in the table it is created only if it is not created yet.

So I created an action in one controller that get recent games of one player and use saveAll to save into the database.

If the database is empty there is no a single problem, of course. But if I receive some games and some of them are already being inserted previously saveAll fails because SOME of the games are already into the database.

```
public function getRecentGames($server = null, $player = null){
    $this->autoRender = false;

    if( !empty($server) && !empty($player) ){
        $r = $this->_getRecentGames($server, $player, $gamesData);
        if ($r['code'] == 200) {
            if ($this->Game->saveAll($gamesData, array('deep' => true))) {
                pr($gamesData);
                prd('Saved');
            } else {
                pr($this->Game->invalidFields());
                prd('Not saved');
            }
        } else {

        }
    }
    return print_r($gamesData, true);
}
```

Basically `saveAll(..)` calls internally `validateMany(..)` which returns false because not every entry is valid and saveAll does not try to save. This is the normal behavior of CakePHP and the way developers want it to work.

So, what should I do?

- Check each game and try to save it?

  `foreach ($games as $game) {
      $this->Model->saveAssociated(..);
  }`
- Modify the behavior of `saveAll(..)` in order to save the valid games and not the invalid ones. (Do you think this should be the default behavior of CakePHP?)
- Other solutions I didn't think(?). Please show me then

Thank you

Comment: It's hard to understand what you are asking for, you may want to reword your question so that the grammar makes a little more sense. It would probably also help if you'd supply some code examples.

Comment: @ndm , I updated, sorry you probably were right

Comment: What do you need the code to do? Do you want to save only the entries that passed validation? Or do you want to save the entries that passed validation and the ones that already exists to be edited?

Comment: Ideally I only want to save the new ones.

Comment: One way you could do it is iterating over the `$this->Game->invalidFields()`, `unset` the invalid records and call `saveAll()` again.

Comment: hi @ndm , I am trying what you proposed me using ```'validate'``` to ```true``` instead of using the default value 'first'. But apparently with ```true``` associated models are not saved. Do you know why this could be?

Answer (score 0):

Well this is the best approach I could think of:

```
$validations = $this->Game->validateMany( $gamesData, array('deep' => true, 'atomic' => false) );
for ($i=count($gamesData)-1; $i>=0; $i--) {
    if (!$validations[$i]) {
        unset($gamesData[$i]);
    }
}
if (!empty($gamesData)) {
    $result = $this->Game->saveAll($gamesData, array('deep' => true, 'validate' => false));
}
```